# Python URL Encoding with lowercase letters?

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, url, encoding

When using `urllib.parse.quote` the encoding is all capitalized. My proxy server is written in C# which excepts the encoding to be lowercased.

For instance, `<` is encoded(UTF-8) as `%3C`. However, C#'s `WebUtility.UrlDecode(request.RawUrl)` is excepting all lowercase lettering: `%3c`. The result is two systems that can't talk to each other.

C# ASP.NET did have another function that worked with uppercase encoding. This function no longer exists. (Retired) [Link to used C# function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.8)

```
import urllib
my_text="?address=This is an Address!&name=This is a test of it all!<.>"
my_url=urllib.parse.quote(my_text)
my_url
```

**I'm hoping to encode the URL on the python side with lowercase letters. Any idea on how to make this happen?**

Another possible solution is decoding the URL with capital letters on the C# side, but there doesn't seem to be a function for this. :(

Comment: C# doesn't expect anything of the kind. `WebUtility.UrlDecode` isn't all that much but *doens't care* about the case. `WebUtility.UrlDecode(System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.example.com/moo?xxx=aaa").ToLower())` works just fine. `WebUtility.UrlEncode` produces *uppercase* URLs, and needless to say, also works with `UrlDecode`

Comment: In other words, no repro. Do you have a *specific* problem, error message or exception text? What proxy do you refer to?

Comment: No error is received. When I execute: 

`String urlDecoded = WebUtility.UrlDecode(request.RawUrl);`

My output is:
 %3Chtml%3E%20%3Cbody%3E%20%3C...

It looks like the UrlDecode is doing nothing to decode the url that was encoded by python.

Comment: To provide a little more detail: I have a HttpListener that monitors a port. If a request is received on that port along with an email subject, To, and HTML message the C# code will send an email via a SMTP server. The only problem I have is the url decoding on the C# side.

Comment: Perhaps the data is being quoted twice?  Can you edit your question to provide an [mcve] that shows how the requests are generated on the Python side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm hoping to encode the URL on the python side with lowercase letters. Any idea on how to make this happen?

We have Regex and it's a powerful weapon. Try this:

```py
import re
import urllib.parse  # I'm curious that you just imported `urllib`.


my_text = "?address=This is an Address!&name=This is a test of it all!<.>"
my_url = re.sub(r'%[0-9A-Z]{2}',                             # pattern
                lambda matchobj: matchobj.group(0).lower(),  # function used to replace matched string
                urllib.parse.quote(my_text))                 # input string
my_url
```

The output is:

```
%3faddress%3dThis%20is%20an%20Address%21%26name%3dThis%20is%20a%20test%20of%20it%20all%21%3c.%3e
```

Compare with the original one:

```
%3Faddress%3DThis%20is%20an%20Address%21%26name%3DThis%20is%20a%20test%20of%20it%20all%21%3C.%3E
```

This will meet your requirement.

---

If you want to process multiple URLs in this way, it is better to use [*regular expression object*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-objects):

```py
import re
import urllib.parse


my_re = re.compile(r'%[0-9A-Z]{2}')  # pattern

my_text = "?address=This is an Address!&name=This is a test of it all!<.>"
my_url = my_re.sub(lambda matchobj: matchobj.group(0).lower(),  # function used to replace matched string
                   urllib.parse.quote(my_text))                 # input string
my_url
```

---

Docs:

- [re — Regular expression operations § re.sub - Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.lower()`

```
my_url="http://mHJKiHgHJKMKLvkdddd.cOm"
my_url.lower()

'http://mhjkihghjkmklvkdddd.com'
```

Comment: WebUtility.UrlDecode doesn't care about letter case anyway

Comment: Thats not good for me because you lower all characters not not just the special chars that are url encoded to ascii.